# DynamoDB FilterExpressions with BETWEEN

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am performing a scan operation on my DynamoDB table then filtering the result to have items between two dates in NODE.js

The DynamoDB table formats data like this:

```
{
      TableName: tableName,
      Item: {
      "visitorID": visitorIDq, // Primary Key
      "dateID":   dateTime, // What I am filtering the scan for
      "visitorName": "END OF Q",
      "employeeName": "END OF Q",
      "comments":  "END OF Q"
}
```

Current code:

```
var date1 = String(threeMonths); // milliseconds since epoch - 3 months in milliseconds 
var date2 = String(dateTime); // milliseconds since epoch aka now
var params2 = {
    TableName: tableName,
    FilterExpression: "dateID BETWEEN :date1 and :date2",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":date1": { "S": date1},
    ":date2": { "S": date2}
            }
};
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR Unable to scan the table. Error JSON: {   "message": "Invalid
>   FilterExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function;
>   operator or function: BETWEEN, operand type: M",   "code":
>   "ValidationException",   "time": "2019-07-06T02:00:44.569Z",
>   "requestId": "REQUESTID1294743204701HHH443",   "statusCode": 400,
>   "retryable": false,   "retryDelay": 26.7865000058784 }

After some internet searching I am kind of stuck, not really find anybody else with this issue in node. Any ideas?

For some reason Stack Overflow is telling me this is mostly code. I thought I did a pretty good job of explaining it and giving details. This is placeholder text because I am tryna post. It is still happening. Details. Details. Details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct resolution:

```
var dateID = String("\""+ threeMonths + "\""); // var for time in milliseconds, stringifying
var params2 = {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':msID' : dateID
  },
  FilterExpression: "dateID >= :msID", // dateID column in DDB is greater than epoch - 3 months
  TableName: "Visitor"
};

JSON.stringify(params2); //params are stringified here for the scan
```

Specifically:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':msID' : "15666767546459" // or whatever value you are comparing, the above resolution has dateID there because its a var getting current time
  }
```